Rollback Mechanism in Salesforce
I'm seeking advice on performing an update operation in my database. Before saving the changes, I need to validate them through a third-party service using Mulesoft. If the response from the service indicates success, I'll proceed with the operation. Otherwise, I'll need to rollback all changes. Any insights or suggestions on how to implement this workflow?

Clearly you cannot do this as part of a DML flow. This is something you must do before performing the DML operation since you cannot do callouts from a trigger.

Is there any approach which we can take so as to stop the operation till the callout response come.

Not once you start the DML. I believe you have two choices: check the remote system first then only on success do the DML or do the DML to a second type of object, like some form of Command object (recording the changes required), use these to trigger the check with the external system and then on success apply the required updates to the target objects. I am unaware of any mechanism to allow synchronous in-DML handling.
